# Principles of immutability and copy-on-write in polars python api

Tags: python-polars

Hi I'm working on this fan fiction project of a full feature + syntax translation of pypolars to R called "minipolars".

I understand the pypolars API e.g. DataFrame in generel elicits immutable-behavior or isch the same as 'copy-on-write' behaviour. Most methods altering the DataFrame object will return a cheap copy.
Exceptions known to me are [DataFrame.extend](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.extend.html#) and the [@columns.setter](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/master/py-polars/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py#L925).
In R, most API's strive for a strictly immutable-behavior. I imagine to both support a strictly immutable behavoir, and optional pypolars-like behavior.
Rust-polars API has many mutable operations + lifetimes and what not, but it is understandably all about performance and expressiveness.

- Are there many more central mutable behavoirs in the pypolars-API?
- Would a pypolars-API with only immutable behavior suffer in performance and expressiveness?

The R library `data.table` API do stray away from immutable-behavoir some times. However all such operations that are mutable are prefixed `set_` or use the set-operator `:=`.

- Is there an obvious way in pypolars to recognize if an operation is mutable or not?

By mutable-behavoir I think of e.g. executing the method `.extend()` after defining variable `df_mutable_copy` and that still affects the value `df_mutable_copy`.

```
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": [4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [10, 20, 30], "bar": [40, 50, 60]})

df_copy = df1
df_copy_old_shape = df_copy.shape

df1.extend(df2)
df_copy_new_shape = df_copy.shape

#extend was a operation with mutable behaviour df_copy was affected.
df_copy_old_shape != df_copy_new_shape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the python polars API is actually a wrapper around polars lazy.

```py
(df.with_columns(..)
   .join(..)
   .groupby()
   .select(..)
```

translates to:

````
```python
(df.lazy().with_columns(..).collect(no_optimization=True)
   .lazy().join(..).collect(no_optimization=True)
   .lazy().groupby().collect(no_optimization=True)
   .lazy().select(..).collect(no_optimization=True)
````

That means that almost all expresions run on the polars query engine. The query engine itself determines if an operation can be done in place, or if it should clone the data (copy on write).

Polars actually has Copy on write on steroids, as it only copies if the data is not shared. If we are the only owner, we mutate in place. We can do this because Rust has a borrow checker, so if we own the data and the ref count is 1, we can mutate the data.

I would recommend you to implement your R-polars API similar to what we do in python. Then all operations can be made pure (e.g. return a new `Series/Expr/DataFrame`) and pollars will decide when to mutate in place.

Don't worry about copying data. All data buffers are wrapped in an `Arc`, so we only increment a reference count.

Comment: Many thanks! Ok so pypolars has strong focus on the behavior and performance of lazy queries. For the eager api there could exist mutable methods such as `.extend` and  `@columns.setter`.
BTW I made the following joke on working with polars copies at a rust meetup in my hometown https://imgur.com/a/BrA9vFj :)