Evaluate expression in polars
How do you evaluate an expression in Rust polars without destroying the dataframe?
For example, I have an expression, for example sum(col('a') + col('b')) * col('c'), and I want to evaluate the expression by computing the sum, but I do not want to turn the dataframe into a lazy dataframe if that means destroying the eager dataframe.
How do you do this?
The best solution I could find was to run Python from within Rust, pass the dataframe to Python, evaluate a Python polars.Expr, and then pass both objects back to Rust.

You can't without cloning (which is probably what python is doing anyway?)

Are you sure? That seems very inefficient

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73934129/ may be relevant. "Don't worry about copying data. All data buffers are wrapped in an Arc, so we only increment a reference count."

A DataFrame contains only a Vec<Series> and Series wraps all its data in Arc so it should be very cheap to clone like @jqurious said: https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.Series.html.
